# Centering a toggle-able div with variable sie

Tags: html, css, popup

I've got a warning/message popup class that is hidden and called trough jQuery, the current method I'm using centers the START of the Div in the page and has weird alignment in mobile devices, how can I make it so the center of the Div is on the center of the page?

I've tried this and they don't work:

```
display:table;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
```

This is my class

```
.popup
{
    position:fixed;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    z-index:1001;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform`:

```
.popup {
    position:fixed;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    z-index:1001;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px 0 #000;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: @Jofran works when I duplicate. Is there something else in your css that may be overriding?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `transform` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hjrsyy18/3/):

```
.popup {
    /* .. Other rules */
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Nope, it just sends the div to the top left corner